# Fast Cholesky decomposition of a Toepllitz matrix via embedding in a circulant & fft

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

As I understand it, the Cholesky decomposition of a Toeplitz matrix can be computed more efficiently by first embedding it in a circulant matrix then using FFT, but I'm having trouble finding any implementations of this approach anywhere, nor description of the specific series of operations I'd need to implement it myself. Help?

Here’s code to construct a Toeplitz, compute the Cholesky decomposition the standard way, then do the circulant embedding:

```
#imports
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz, circulant, cholesky
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft

# construct the Toeplitz matrix
t = toeplitz(np.array([1., 0.5]))  + ( 1e-6 * np.eye(2) )
print(t)
# [[1.000001 0.5     ]
#  [0.5      1.000001]]

# compute the cholesky the standard way
chol_ltri_std = cholesky(t,lower=True)
print(chol_ltri_std)
#    [[1.0000005 , 0.        ]
#     [0.49999975, 0.86602613]]

# verify:
chol_ltri_std @ chol_ltri_std.T # should == t

#embed in circulant (maybe needs to be a different embedding? Reflected & periodic don’t seem to work either)
c = circulant(np.concatenate([t[0,:],t[0,:-1][::-1]]))
print(c)
# [[1.000001 1.000001 0.5     ]
#  [0.5      1.000001 1.000001]
#  [1.000001 0.5      1.000001]]

#attempt at fft-based cholesky decomposition
eigenvalues = fft(c)
sqrt_eigenvalues = np.sqrt(eigenvalues)
inverse_fft_real = ifft(sqrt_eigenvalues).real 

print(inverse_fft_real)
# yields:
# [[0.93529519 0.52704649 0.11879779]
#  [0.52704649 0.11879779 0.93529519]
#  [0.93529519 0.11879779 0.52704649]]
#but none of these values match the elements of chol_ltri_std
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for this understanding?  In fact, can you exhibit a positive-definite circulant matrix?

Comment: @whuber see updated post

Comment: The circulant in your example is not a symmetric matrix, and `cholesky` function assumes that the matrix is symmetric and works on the lower triangular part, so it is not the cholesky decomposition of the circulant. You can check that `np.transpose(chol_ltri_std)@chol_ltri_std` does not coincide with `x`

Comment: Good catch @vladimir-lysikov. In my playing I'd forgotten that my actual aim was to achieve cholesky decomposition of a Toeplitz matrix, which I'd heard could be achieved by embedding in a circulant then doing FFT, but in that case the point of comparison should be standard cholesky decomposition of the toeplitz. I've updated the title, post & code.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you embedding does, as the Toeplitz matrix is not a contiguous submatrix of the resulting circulant. I think this question may do better on scicomp or math stackexchange.

Comment: Your second ($3\times 3$) circulant is not symmetric.  The problem is that most Toeplitz matrices are not circulants.  Moreover, to apply a Cholesky decomposition you *must* have a symmetric real or Hermitian matrix (obviously, because the product $X=LL^*$ is manifestly Hermitian).  Thus, you need to focus your examples and experimentation on symmetric Toeplitz matrices and embed them in symmetric circulant matrices.  The latter have an easily computed set of eigenvectors. That decomposition is *not* Cholesky, but it *induces* a Cholesky decomposition of the original Toeplitz block.

Comment: Oh! Ah, I think I found the root of my misunderstanding. Where the post suggests I'd heard there was a fast method involving circulant embedding and FFT for computing the Cholesky decomposition of a Toeplitz, in fact it's that there's a fast method involving circulant embedding & FFT to generate *samples from a GP* (ex. Percival 2006) Usually sampling from a GP involves computing the Cholesky decomposition, hence my memory confusion.